# Jquery post causes apache to hang

Tags: php, jquery

I'm filling in element values in YUI panel (DOMInserted) via jquery

This is the php

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect('sql', 'admin', '123');
    mysql_select_db('sql');
    $data_parent_type0 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data_parent_type0']);
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT id,name FROM email_templates WHERE description = "'.$data_parent_type0.'" AND deleted = 0');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>' . "\n";
}
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This is the JQUERY

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', '#composeHeaderTable0', function(event) {
$("#data_parent_type0").click(function() {
    var data_parent_type0 = $('#data_parent_type0').val();
    //alert(data_parent_type0);
    $.post("dbcall.php", { data_parent_type0: data_parent_type0},
    function(result){
    //alert(result);
    $("#email_template0").html(result);
});
});
});
```

It works but causes Apache to hang.

Comment: How big is your result set ? Is it huge ?

Comment: I resolved it. I had to unbind the click(function)